# On iOS 12 (beta), AppAuth iOS seems to not have SSO between app and web

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, appauth

Today I am testing AppAuth-iOS apps on multiple iOS version (iOS 8-11), and AppAuth-iOS have SSO between apps and webs.

However, when I tested the same apps on **iOS 12 beta** (both on real device and emulator), I found that there are **no SSO between app and web**. SSO only exists between apps for iOS 12.

I would like to know the following:

- Anyone else is experiencing the same problems?
- Is that an intentional behavior for iOS 12, [Possibly because of the new component ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession)? Or is that just a bug?

My setup:

- AppAuth-iOS 0.94.0 (So ASWebAuthenticationSession is implemented)
- Protocol: OAuth 2
- Scheme: Custom Uri scheme
- idp Cookie: Persistent Cookie

---

As of 17 Sep 2018, iOS 12 official launch, the problem seems to still exists. Anyone manage to make this work?